# RmiDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: java, weblogic, datasource, jndi

Below is the code to connect to remote database. Datasource is configured on a remote weblogic server. I want to use the same jndi. I used ddmp-wlfullclient-12.2.1.3.jar as dependency.

This program is a standalone java application.

```
Hashtable<String,String> ht = new Hashtable<>();
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://<servername>:<port>");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup ("jdbc/<jndiname>");
java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("select * from table");
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
```

But I am getting the below exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_12214_WLStub cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
```

Could someone guide me in getting it resolved.

I don't want to maintain credentials in my program in any format